# Outlook integration with ifd in crm 2013 on-premises

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

How can I send email as a notification to certain people in CRM 2013 on-premises with ifd? Like I want an email notification to be sent to certain people in hierarchy whenever a salesperson makes changes in opportunity or add anything?

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: If you have your email router setup, you don't necessarily need to integrate Outlook.  Just use a workflow and as a step, select Send A Email.  You can put all of your logic in the workflow itself.  Or, are your requirements more complex than that?  Your systemuser table contains a Primary Email address field which you can put the users email address in.  You can also create distribution lists through queues and as the email, use an outlook group.

Answer (score 0):

> You can write a plugin on update of opportunity, that will trigger
>   whenever you update opportunity record.  In plugin you need to write
>   the piece of code which will send notification emails to the specific
>   contact list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question:

1. Set up Outlook or Server which will send emails. Check: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscoil/archive/2014/02/05/crm-2013-exchange-synchronization
2. Customize CRM to create and send emails. For this you will have to create workflow with "Send Email" step or plug-in on the update/Create of the Opportunity entity depending on the Business requirements you have.